# How to mount four 6-wire 10V load cells on Arduino or Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arduino, amplifier, raspberry-pi, load-cell

I want to connect four 6-wire load cells (Tedea Huntleigh Compression & Tension Load Cell 300kg, 15V dc, IP67, [product page](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/load-cells/4140865/) and [datasheet](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/010f/0900766b8010f46f.pdf)) into an Arduino or Raspberry Pi and get four independent readings. This is my first time dealing with load cells.

I would like to get an accuracy of 2kg and a range of 25-100 kg on each load cell. The load cells have a recommended excitation of 10V.

My understanding is that, to get a working prototype, I can:

- not use the two sense wires in the load cell (first suggestion by DaveEvans in [this Arduino thread](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=574058.0))
- use a breadboard, even though [it's not meant for a sensitive circuit](http://www.hw2sw.com/2011/10/24/liquid-filling-machine-part-2/)
- use the 5V supply from the Arduino, which halves the output voltage from the load cell but does not require an extra power supply or an booster converter, with some decrease in precision of the reading
- use an INA125P amplifier and the wiring [in the first link of this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153961/connecting-a-small-load-cell-to-arduino-using-ina125p) and connect each load cell to a single analog pin in the Arduino Uno, which only has 5 analog pins
- calibrate the reading from each load cell with two known weights and extrapolate linearly

Would this work? Which shortcuts would be the first to consider to improve the precision of the readings?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi does not have an ADC, so you would need to add that in to make it work...This makes going straight to an Arduino a good choice (provided the built in ADCs on the Arduino are adequate for your needs).

Comment: Please reference the load cell that you will use, There is no point in commenting what an analog system can or can't do if you don't know what the sensor is. Also comment on the accuracy and range that you'd like to obtain.

Comment: @mmorin  Breadboard is fine for a load cell amplifier.  It's a DC circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried two ways: with a pre-programmed SparkFun OpenScale and with a custom circuit with Arduino Nano. Both ways do without the Sense cables, which serve for more accurate readings. They also use 5V instead of 10V, which reduces precision but seems OK for my application (see Elliot Alderson's answer for an excellent guidance on calculating precision and the difference with accuracy). Both use a serial interface, such as the one from [the Arduino app](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Donate) (choose `Tools > Port`, then `Tools > Serial Monitor`), and both use components specifically for this purpose of load cells.

## Easy way with SparkFun OpenScale

SparkFun has an [OpenScale](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13261) made specifically for load cells and provides a [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/openscale-applications-and-hookup-guide#hardware-features) to connect to them. You can calibrate the measurements via the serial interface, as well as other settings. The OpenScale is basically an Arduino mounted on a printed circuit board, so you can also modify [the open-source code](https://github.com/sparkfun/OpenScale) and flash it to the OpenScale, e.g. with the Arduino app.

## Custom way with micro-controller and HX711

The HX711 is an amplifier specifically for load cells (and used in the OpenScale board). I found [this tutorial](https://makersportal.com/blog/2019/5/12/arduino-weighing-scale-with-load-cell-and-hx711) on using an HX711 amplifier and analogue-to-digital converter. It took readings from the load cell and sent to the Arduino nano with 24 bits of depth. See that website for the circuit and for installing the QHX711 library. See also [this tutorial](https://makersportal.com/blog/2019/5/12/arduino-weighing-scale-with-load-cell-and-hx711) for the LCD1602 screen, and [this tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/button) for adding a push button. The result is here:

[image: Circuit with Arduino Nano, HX711, and load cell]

And I modified the original code to refactor the readings, add a tare button, and include a LCD1602 screen:

```c
// Liquid Crystal Display directions from
// https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/najad/interfacing-lcd1602-with-arduino-764ec4
// www.diyusthad.com
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// HX711 and load cell directions from
// https://makersportal.com/blog/2019/5/12/arduino-weighing-scale-with-load-cell-and-hx711
#include <Q2HX711.h>

// Constant variables for display
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;

// Constant variables for load cell
const byte HX711_DATA_PIN = 7;
const byte HX711_CLOCK_PIN = 8;
const float KNOWN_WEIGHT = 199.0; // calibrated mass to be added
const long AVG_NUM = 10; // amount of averages for each mass measurement

// Constant variables for the pushbutton
const int buttonPin = 10;

// Global variables for load cell
float slope = 0.0;
long tare = 0L;

// Declare HX711 and LCD
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
Q2HX711 hx711(HX711_DATA_PIN, HX711_CLOCK_PIN);

long take_reading() {
  long x = 0L;
  for (int i = 0; i < AVG_NUM; i++) {
    delay(10);
    x += hx711.read();
  }
  return x / AVG_NUM;
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial connection at this baud
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Initialize LCD
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  // allow load cell and hx711 to settle
  delay(1000);

  // Take initial reading for tare
  tare = take_reading();

  // Request known weight
  char buffer[16];
  dtostrf(KNOWN_WEIGHT, 3, 1, buffer);

  Serial.print("Add known weight (g): ");
  Serial.println(buffer);
  lcd.print("Add known weight (g)");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(buffer);
  // calibration procedure (mass should be added equal to KNOWN_WEIGHT)
  while (hx711.read() < tare + 10000) {
    delay(100);
  }
  long reading = take_reading();
  Serial.println(reading);

  // This slope is fixed throughout
  slope = KNOWN_WEIGHT / (reading - tare);

  Serial.println("Calibration Complete");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Weight (g):      ");
}

void loop() {
  // averaging reading
  long reading = take_reading();

  // calculating mass based on calibration and linear fit
  float mass = (reading - tare) * slope;

  // Format string
  char weight[6];
  dtostrf(mass, 3, 1, weight);
  Serial.println(weight);

  char buffer[16];
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  sprintf(buffer, "%16s", weight);
  lcd.print(buffer);

  // Check if the pushbutton is pressed. If it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (digitalRead(buttonPin)== HIGH) {
    while(digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH) {
      delay(100);
    }
    // Lazy debounce
    delay(100);
    tare = reading;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use a load cell rated for 200kg full load, with an output of 2 mV/V, and a supply voltage of 5V, then your output voltage will be 10mV for a 200kg load or 5mV for a 100kg load. A change in the load of 2kg will cause a voltage change of 0.1mV.

If you are digitizing this with a **perfect** ADC using a reference voltage of 5V you need at least 16 bits of resolution to see such a change in voltage. This will not happen with an Arduino. The ADC on an Arduino has 10 bits of resolution, so it can see changes of about 5mV. And we haven't even talked about **accuracy** yet.

So, you need to provide a differential gain of at least 100X if you want to use an Arduino. Otherwise, you need to find a better ADC. You also need to make sure that your analog reference voltage for the ADC, and the excitation voltage for the load cells, is as stable and accurate as you want your measurements to be.

Comment: Good points! Can I amplify 100x with INA125P? For the alternative ADC, [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38688/how-to-connect-load-cell-to-arduino) mentions LTC2400 and LTC2440 for 24-bit measurements. Those would work, right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to chase a sequence of links. Provide links to the manufacturer's data sheets for these parts. You should be able to read the INA datasheet and see for yourself whether it supports gain of 100. As for the ADC, we try not to recommend specific parts on this site.

Comment: You are right, sorry. The [INA125 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina125.pdf) says "A single external resistor sets any gain from 4 to 10,000."

Comment: [The StackExchange thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38688/how-to-connect-load-cell-to-arduino) mentions three tutorials for high-precision ADCs: [the LTC2400 for 24-bit single-ended measurements](http://interface.khm.de/index.php/lab/interfaces-advanced/connect-a-ltc2400-high-precision-24-bit-analog-to-digital-converter/), [the LTC2440 for 24-bit differential measurements](http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4247&p=42051), and [the MCP3422/MCP3424 for 18-bit differential measurements](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=12269).

Comment: You need to provide links to the **datasheets** of the parts you are asking about, not links to other web pages that discuss the parts.

Comment: Yes, of course, my bad. The datasheets for the components mentioned [in this StackExchange thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38688/how-to-connect-load-cell-to-arduino) are [the LTC2400 for 24-bit single-ended measurements](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2400fa.pdf), [the LTC2440 for 24-bit differential measurements](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc2440.html), and [the MCP3422/MCP3424 for 18-bit differential measurements](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22088c.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

You have a system composed of FOUR resistors, of value about 400 ohms each.

Power them from +5 volts, install a 0.1uF capacitor across the differential output wires, and wire that to the differential inputs of your microcontroller.

The common-mode output of the bridge will be approximately VDD/2 or 2.5 volts.

If you don't have differential inputs to the MCU, you can still wire the bridge outputs to TWO inputs of the ADC, and subtract the reported-voltages. Some errors will occur.

For noise rejection (switching power supplies, motor-commutator sparks, AM radio transmitters, cellphones, etc) consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSUu2W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I would like to get an independent measurement from each load cell. Does your circuit provide that?

Comment: If you use a dual 4:1 analog mux (MC140xx or MC40xx), this will work.